# Unity IoC: The current type x is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

In my ASP.net MVC application, I keep getting this intermittent Yellow Screen of Death (YSOD) with the error:

> The current type, x, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

I know it has something to do with Unity IoC, but I'm not sure what exactly. My Interfaces / Classes follow a well defined pattern which is:

***ISupplierService*** will be implemented by **SupplierService** and so on.

The `UnityConfig.cs` file has the following:

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
  public static void RegisterComponents()
  {
    var container = new UnityContainer();

    container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(), WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface, WithName.Default);
    container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
    container.RegisterType<ManageController>(new InjectionConstructor());
    container.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
    container.RegisterType<DbContext, PdContext>();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
  }
}
```

And in my `SupplierController.cs` I have the following constructor:

```
public class SupplierController : BaseController
{
  private readonly ISupplierService _supplierService;

  public SupplierController(ISupplierService supplierService)
  {
    if (supplierService == null)
    {
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(supplierService));
    }

    _supplierService = supplierService;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you registering `ISupplierService`?

Comment: I thought here >> `container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(), WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface, WithName.Default);`? Doesn't that tell the container to follow that naming convention I mentioned?

Comment: No, I didn't think I had to, cause locally, things work fine, I can hit the `SupplierController` and do CRUD with no problems. If I do that, then I'll have to do it for each `ISomeThing` and `SomeThing`. I mean what's the point of that configuration line?

Comment: Using the same WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface I'm running into the same problem, all my other `IClassName` / `ClassName`combos work except for a new one I just added.  Even copied the ClassName to IClassName to fix a typo, and still no dice

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem now.

Your implementation class `SupplierService` doesn't implement the interface `ISupplierService`.

You can either add the `ISupplierService` to your class declaration, or have BaseController implement `ISupplierService`.

```
public class SupplierController : BaseController, IServiceSupplier
{
  //.
  //.
  //.
}
```

I just realized my same mistake after coming back into the project after a while... :)